# React-Native 0.63 not able to access Device Storage images in Android 10

Tags: android, image, react-native, android-emulator

I am using React Native 0.63. I wanted to display images in a FlatList from my phone's device storage and was using `<Image/>` for the `renderItem` prop of FlatList.
Using the `source` prop, I added a `uri` key but I am still not able to see the images. The image tiles are being generated in the FlatList and I am able to see the thin scrollbar on the right when I try to scroll over the list.

This is what I am doing to display the image. (The `uri` used here is of an image which I got from the [`CameraRoll.getPhotos()`](https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll) API)

```
<Image
 source={{ uri: 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Twitter/20201019_160855.jpg'}}
 style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}
/>
```

I have made sure about the following:

1. Allowed `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions for the application.
2. Added `file://` prefix to the file.
3. Made sure `source={{ uri: ... }}` in `<Image/>` works for external links, tried using Google logo, random jpegs from the internet.

Another thing which I noticed is, I am using Samsung phone with Android 10 on my device where I am facing this issue. I tried running this on the Google Nexus 5 Android Emulator which also runs on Android 10 and works perfectly fine (By this, I mean I am able to access the emulator's device storage and not using the exact same `uri` specified above).

**UPDATE:** *Tried compiling the application on Android 7, the above thing is working fine. Any issue with the the SDK Versions?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you getting a permission denied error?

This might be helpful:
https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/1259

Something to try adding:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

... to the  tag in your AndroidManifest.xml.

---

**Warning:**

From May 5 2021 onwards:
**Play Store will not accept this implementation** and remove all apps using it except if the app functionally really requires it and it needs to be requested.

The implementation will need to use Scoped Storage.

Comment: Yes, adding this worked. Also, need to make one more change, In the project build.gradlew file, you need to change your `compileSdkVersion` as 29.

Comment: Adding to the above comment, there is no such permission denied error. This is an issue for Android 10 mainly, your need to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` for accessing the External storage.

Answer (score 0):

Are the images appearing on the emulator correctly?

If the issue is only on your device, you will want to check you've added
`android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` and requested perission to use file storage

See: [Usage - react-native CameraRoll](https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll#usage)

Comment: 1. Yes, the images are appearing on the emulator correctly. 

2. I have added READ and WRITE External Storage permissions and are enabled in the App Info section.

Comment: Yes it Appears  fine in both emulator and Device as well

Answer (score 0):

```
This can be helpful: https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/1259

In manifest
 android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
  
 <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> 


  build.gradle

 // camera    
    compileSdkVersion = 29
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found Storage Permission wasn't working in the Samsung Phone

so i added following in the

> android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

More Importantly This fixed my Issue :

> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>`

then check for the Permission as regular and it will work

My Config for the React-native APP

```
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-native": "0.70.6",

buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 22
compileSdkVersion = 33
targetSdkVersion = 33
```

This Worked in My case 
Happy Hacking